# ASP.NET controller name as variable

Tags: asp.net

I have a controller that extends `ApiController`

Is there a way to create method in that controller that will allow me to use url such as:  `/api/<id>/user` ?

Comment: Yes you can define new route mapping. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: @SelimYıldız I've been trying for a few days but I still can't figure out how to map ``/api/{id}/user`` route. I have no idea how to direct it to a controller without actually naming it

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no use in the style you want.

> /api/id/user

You can try it

> /api/user/id

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public void Get(string id)
{
    return Ok(id);
}
```

Comment: Well, ``user`` and ``id`` were just an example. If you're doubting whether there's use, Sentry uses such url [link](https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/store/) And that's something I'm trying to copy